# Is xfs_fsr safe to interrupt?

Tags: xfs

Is it safe to interrupt (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>) a long running `xfs_fsr` job?

I'm attempting to defragment a very large XFS volume.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like all filesystem manipulation tools, `xfs_fsr` takes care of leaving the filesystem in a consistent state, in case the machine crashes (due to a power failure, for example). Unless you're unlucky and encounter a bug, that is — filesystem drivers are more complex than they look, especially as they are written for speed.

If you interrupt `xfs_fsr` cleanly (with any of the usual signals SIGINT, SIGHUP, SIGTERM or SIGQUIT), it takes care to write where it left off in `/var/tmp/.fsrlast` (or the file indicated with the `-f` option). So you can safely interrupt it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and restart it again with the same options later to complete the job.